# Debugging app with CImg library included

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cimg

I'm writing program to analyze 3D raw images. I have strange problem with loading this files. During debugging:

```
(...)
string input_filename = file_i;
CImg<unsigned char> img_org(500, 500, 500, 1);
img_org.load_raw(file_i, 500, 500, 500, 1);
(...)
```

I have IO Exception, looks like: [image]

What is more, after compile, program works ok. It's important for me to debug entire program, because I must look into further functions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found out that debugger is looking for my .raw file in different folder. It was silly question, but already I have the answer.